# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away (SQL: select * from `listings` where `is_active` = 1 order by `created_at` desc)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, lamp

I have tried to set up a laravel jobboard on a LAMP server with php 8.0, Apache 2 and MariaDB. After a few solved problems I got the above error message. I'm not really in PHP and MySQL. Therefore I'm not quiet concious about what I`m doing.

Thanks for every help.

PS: The server is a remote server with CentOS 8. Therefore I cant run it on localhost.

Comment: Check the MySQL error log also test the query you arerunnng and see if the timeouts are exceeded

Comment: It sounds like the MySQL settings in your .env file are invalid or the database connection can't made.